# OrbitControls & TransformControls per viewport

Tags: three.js

I have a scene split in 4 viewports with 2 PerspectiveCamera and 2 OrthographicCamera.

Live Example: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Viewports-Quad.html

When I use OrbitControls for the 1st camera I have to assign the dom element which is the whole canvas scene and not the particular view. Same happens with TransformControls.

How can I use them per camera viewport?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an OrbitControls instance for every viewport but the same DomElement, thus:

```
controls.push(new THREE.OrbitControls( views[0].camera, renderer.domElement ));
controls.push(new THREE.OrbitControls( views[1].camera, renderer.domElement ));
controls.push(new THREE.OrbitControls( views[2].camera, renderer.domElement ));
```

It is enough to add just one event listener:

```
controls[0].addEventListener( 'change', draw );
```

However I find this solution to be slow and Im still looking for a better option.

Comment: perhaps I misunderstood the orig question but yes: that's what my solution is meant to do. If you move the scene through one viewport, it should change in all of them.